# Not possible to use formula on Rich Text field?

Tags: formula, formula-field, richtextarea

I want to find out how long my Rich Text fields are in a specific object. When creating a Formula field with the goal of using LEN(MyField__c) I get thrown the following error:

```
Error: You referenced an unsupported field type called "Rich Text Area" using the following field: MyField__c
```

Is there a way to calculate the length of a Rich Text field any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation you are not allowed to use RichText fields in formula https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329422&type=1&mode=1

If you want to calculate length of data, I would suggest to use trigger for it.

You can simply use length function for it just make sure to sanitize your rich text field first. For example like :

> 1. Remove html tags using : stripHtmlTags()
> 2. Dont count multiple spaces : .normalizeSpace()
> 3. If you dont even want to count white spaces you can use regex to
>    replace all white spaces with '' or you can use deleteWhitespace()
>    function introduced for Strings.

Example :

Assuming field is on account

```
for (Account a : trigger.new){

String temp = a.fieldName__c.normalizeSpace().stripHtmlTags();
Integer count = temp.length();

}
```

Now after having the count you can save it in some other field or throw an error depending on yourscenario.